# How to store elements to an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, store

I got again tiny problem I would like to store strings in array I got following code:

```
echo -e "Enter an amount"
read n 
for  ((i=0;i<n;i++)); 
do 
echo "Enter number $i " 
read ${array[$i]} 
done 
echo -e "$array[@]}"
```

Can you have a quick look a help me ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 5 should probably read as:

```
read array[$i]
```

`${array[$i]}`, which is what you have at present, will output the value of the element of the array with the subscript $i.  The `read` command reads user input into a specified variable, so you need to specify the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

you could also write

```
array=()
for  ((i=0; i<n; i++)); do 
    read -p "Enter number $i " 
    array+=($REPLY)
done
```